# Skype on Mac prompts to install helper tool and requires administrator login

Tags: mac, permissions, skype

I have Skype installed on Mac OS 10.14.1. This also was happening on previous versions of the OS.

When there is an update available for Skype and a standard user is logged in, they get prompted with "Skype is trying to add a new helper tool. Enter an administrator's name and password to allow this."

I followed the suggestions elsewhere:

- Open the terminal and change the owner to wheel: `sudo chown -R $USER:wheel /Applications/Skype.app`
- Open the "get info" box for the Skype app in Applications. Add the standard user to "sharing & permissions" with read & write access.
- In the same info box, set the standard user as the file owner.

None of those suggestions allows a standard user to install skype updates without administrator intervention.

How can I allow a standard user to install updates for Skype without intervention?

Comment: As no-one's picked up on this yet... I think your only chance is if you find what it's trying to install & to where. You *might* be able to add perms for there, though I honestly doubt it will work. Basically, you need admin perms to do installations, that's the whole idea.

Comment: The steps in [this question in the Apple section](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/335863/annoyance-latest-version-of-skype-under-standard-non-admin-user-on-macos-10-1) may work for you.

Answer (score 1):

The second comment seems to be the way to solve the problem that Skype does NOT update; we continually have to "install the helper app". Regardless, skype works fine without taking the step, but it is an annoyance.

The purpose of running non-administrator is to prevent a user to accidentally or by social engineering attack "install something bad" into the system. It's an important line. Your suggested workarounds break this line by either weakening the permissions on an important system area (the applications folder) or "elevating" the permission of the user by increasing run-time permissions. The installer *should* be asking for administrator intervention when changing a system area.

Apple's SIP (System Integrity Protection) goes a step further to prevent the file permission changes you attempted from working as expected, and [in Mojave this protection was extended to third party applications](https://blog.macsales.com/45473-we-explain-what-system-integrity-protection-on-mac-is-and-how-to-control-it/):

> SIP in macOS Mojave
>   Apple includes a number of new security-related upgrades in Mojave, but for SIP the big change is that it was extended to cover third-party apps and not just those supplied by Apple. This should protect third-party apps from being tampered with, having code injected, or having processes attached to them, all common techniques for gaining control of an app or its services.

This type of protection goes beyond system permissions and really helps protect the System from attacks.

Unfortunately software updates come more often than regular installations so they pose a unique problem.

If you are an administrator and need to temporarily "elevate the privilege" of a user to administrator for a *specific* action, there is a tool called JAMF ( see https://www.jamf.com/solutions/industries/business/ ) that can help you manage that across a large number of computers. We have been using it to good effect to deal with software updates, and to allow users to install software that has been blessed using special packages distributed on demand. This is the easiest way IMHO to scale administrators to a large group that needs to manage Macs.

As painful as it seems, it is true that computer experts should be left in charge of decisions about changing the system; indeed, the number 1 virus method right now for macintosh is "fake updates". Apple is doing the right thing here; when you have a large number of users, tools such as JAMF will help you scale your administrative power to a large number of users.